# Using prototypes to gain more performance

Tags: javascript, prototype

Say I have 100 boxes that inherit the same properties from this constructor:

```
const Box = function() {

    this.element = document.createElement("div");
    this.painted = false;

    this.init = function() {

        this.element.className = "box";

        this.element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
            console.log("you are touching this box!");
            this.change_color("red");
            this.painted = true;
        });
    }

    this.change_color = (color) => this.element.style.background = color;

}
```

Now, as I understand, there is no way I can use Prototypes in the `.addEventListener` because each box needs its listener. But what about the function `this.change_color`? Does each box really need to have this function? Can I make a prototype out of it? (I am guessing not because it uses the box's element, which is a local variable, am I correct?)

Or, let's say I want to make a function that colors all the boxes in my page. How would you go about making a Prototype to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a `prototype` function you can simply use `this` which will refer to the actual instance of a Box class that you created. Thus you can create a `prototype` for both the `init` and `change_color` function, like so:

```js
const Box = function(boxName) {
    this.element = document.createElement("div");
    this.painted = false;
    this.myname = boxName;
}

Box.prototype.init = function() {
  this.element.className = "box";
  this.element.innerText = this.myname;

  this.element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    // console.log("you are touching this box!");
    this.change_color("red");
    this.painted = true;
  });
  
  this.element.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    this.change_color("green");
    this.painted = true;
  });
}

Box.prototype.change_color = function(color) {
  this.element.style.background = color;
}

const box1 = new Box('box1');
box1.init();

const box2 = new Box('box2');
box2.init();

document.body.append(box1.element);
document.body.append(box2.element);
```

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using classes and the prototype method, your code would look like:

```
class Box {
  constructor() {
    this.element = document.createElement("div");
    this.painted = false;
  }
  init() {
    this.element.className = "box";
    this.element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      console.log("you are touching this box!");
      this.change_color("red");
    });
  }
  change_color(color) {
    this.element.style.background = color;
  }
}
```

Now, `init` and `change_color` are on `Box.prototype`, rather than being directly on each instance.

> Or, let's say I want to make a function that colors all the boxes in my page. How would you go about making a Prototype to do so?

One option is to save every Box instance in an array in the constructor, then iterate over it, eg:

```
const boxes = [];
// ...
constructor() {
  boxes.push(this);
}
// ...
boxes.forEach(box => box.change_color('green'));
```

If each box has had its `init` called by the time you want to color all boxes, you could also append a style tag, no iteration nor arrays necessary:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
  .box {
    background-color: green;
  }
`;
```

Comment: oh that's nice. so instead of doing "Box.prototype.blabla" I can just define Box as a class and set the prototypes within it. anyways, it kinda confuses me--how does JS know which box needs to change its color when using the 'change_color' Prototype? does it pass 'this.element' as an argument to 'change_color', just like a pointer?

Comment: `this.change_color("red");` looks up on the `this` object (the box instance) for a `change_color` property. When that property is found, it invokes that function with a calling context (a `this`) of the box instance, since the function is not an arrow function. (arrow functions inherit `this` from the outer scope; non-arrow functions `this` depend on their calling context)

Comment: awesome! so that means that the Prototype function `change_color` doesn't loop over all the boxes to find the `this` box, right? it basically sends `this` as an argument to `change_color` so it knows what box it is, right?

Comment: Yes, you can think of `this` as a kind of argument.